# Do HTML email templates require the use of the style attribute?

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates

Are there scenarios where it is (for some reason) required to place the CSS rule inside the `style` attribute of the HTML tag directly instead of placing the CSS rule inside a selector in the STYLE element in the HEAD of the HTML email template?

(I am asking for the most common CSS selectors, like type, class, ID, descendant combinations)

***Follow-up question:***

Gmail seems to be the only relevant email service that does not support the STYLE element. Why is that? (What's the reasoning behind this decision from Google?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for example google gmail won't handle the STYLE element in the HEAD.

Look at this site for email clients and what they can/can't do regarding css: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: +1 OK, so Gmail and the older versions of Lotus Notes do not support the STYLE element **at all**. Is there a reason (explanation) for Gmail being so backward in this issue? (Yahoo and Hotmail support it.)

Comment: Google puts in their documentation that it is because their UI relies heavily on stylesheets they do not support custom style sheets for emails.  Here is the url http://mail.google.com/mail/help/accessibility.html and look in this section 'Section 1194.22 Web-based Internet Information and Applications'

Answer (score 1):

Style attribute is supported in most of the email clients but not all. For example Gmail's mobile app tends to [removes head tag and classes](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4760488?hl=en&authuser=1).
It will be better if you use inline css instead of an external and internal one.