# Is safe to put html style tag into body tags coding html emails?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am coding a html email template. All my code is inline. There are  media queries between `<style>` tag inside the `<head>` tag.

Can I put the `<style>` tag inside the `<body>` tag?
Would that work with all major email clients?

Comment: what's your definition of "mail client"? many webmails will strip css since the inline css can break the containing web page. outlook's rendering engine is made of rotten chewing gum and moldy spit, and can barely handle not suiciding on a good day...

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224422/will-it-be-a-wrong-idea-to-have-style-in-body

Comment: Take a look at http://webstackoflove.com/building-responsive-transactional-html-email-templates-doesnt-have-to-suck/ for multiple options you have when creating html emails.

Comment: Thank you Marc. With email clients, I am referring a computer program used to access and manage a user's email. It doesn't mater if is web-based or local software installed on your computer or mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems client dependent. Check out a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014600/do-html-email-templates-require-the-use-of-the-style-attribute).

Some clients will support the use of styling in the body, but generally not in the head. Since there is really no way to incorporate css, it makes sense that this would be the case.

Comment: Please don't answer like this, flag the question as duplicate of the auestion you're linking to.

Comment: Thank you, Kaleb. I will take note of that.

Answer (score 3):

Style tag inside the body has almost identical compatability to a style tag in the head. Each client offers different quirks with this, so overall I would recommend using style in head unless you are unable to.

For example Gmail will strip the style tag regardless where you put it.  Your best bet is to test continuously using a service like Litmus or Email on Acid.

Good reference for CSS compatability in email is https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thank you  so much @Gortonington. In this case I don't have choice. The company that will send the broadcast on my behalf require no CSS inside head tag. I always prefer to put CSS in head tag. Even when I am coding emails.